# Prettier removing {" "} in .jsx file

Tags: reactjs, formatting, vscode-extensions, prettier

I have the following block of code in my `.jsx` file:

```
      <div className="">
        <h1 className="">
          The Next <br className="sm:block hidden" /> {" "}
          <span className="text-gradient">Generation </span> {" "}
          Payment
        </h1>
      </div>
```

but prettier removes the second `{" "}` as follows:

```
      <div className="">
        <h1 className="">
          The Next <br className="sm:block hidden" /> {" "}
          <span className="text-gradient">Generation </span>
          Payment
        </h1>
      </div>
```

It also happens in other parts of my code, removing `{" "}`s.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this problem.

All I could find was `prettier.bracketSpacing` in `prettier` configurations which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
const space = " ";
return ( ...
<div className="">
   <h1 className="">
       The Next <br className="sm:block hidden" /> {space}
       <span className="text-gradient">Generation </span> {space}
       Payment
   </h1>
</div>
```